# JavaScript simple script won't load

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this simple script but I comment it and tried just to window.alert and nothing happens. It just wont work, simple window alert so other code wont work too. It looks like the javascript is not loaded into page. Any idea how to solve this?
Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vesanje</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            trenutna rec: <span id="trenutna_rec"></span>
            <br>
            broj pokusaja: <span id="br_pokusaja"></span>
            <br>
            trenutno slovo: <input type="text" id="slovo">
            <br>
            koriscena slova: <input type="text" id="koriscena_slova" readonly>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="zameni pojavljivanja" id="dugme">
        </div>

        <canvas id="platno" height="" width="">

        </canvas>

        <script type='text/javascript'> 
            window.alert("kliks");
            /*
            window.rec="javascript";
            window.alert("test");
            var trenutna_rec = document.querySelector("#trenutna_rec");
            var trenutna_rec_niska = new Array();
            for(let i=0; i<window.rec.length; i++){
                trenutna_rec_niska[i]= "_ ";
            }
            trenutna_rec.textContent = trenutna_rec_niska.join("");

            var br_pokusaja = document.querySelector("#br_pokusaja");
            var br_pokusaja_vrednost=0;
            br_pokusaja.textContent=0;

            var tekuce_slovo = document.querySelector("#slovo");

            var koriscena_slova = document.querySelector("#koriscena_slova");
            var koriscena_slova_niz = new Array();

            var dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
            dugme.onclick=function(){
                //procita tekuce slovo
                var ts=tekuce_slovo.value;

                var zamene=0;

                //spreciti unos unetih slova
                if(koriscena_slova_niz.indexOf(ts)!=-1){
                    return;
                    tekuce_slovo.value="";
                }

                //provelrimo da li se slovo nalazi u reci
                for(let i=0; i<window.rec.length; i++){
                    if(window.rez[i]==ts){
                        trenutna_rec_niska[i]=ts;
                        zamene++;
                    }
                }

                //izvrsimo zamenu ako je potrebno
                //ispisati novu tekucu rec
                trenutna_rec.textContent = trenutna_rec_niska.join("");

                //ispisati novi br pokusaja
                br_pokusaja_vrednost++;
                br_pokusaja.textContent = br_pokusaja_vrednost;

                //dopisemo korisceno slovo
                koriscena_slova_niz.push(ts);
                koriscena_slova.textContent=koriscena_slova_niz.join("");

                tekuce_slovo.value = "";
            }/*
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not closing your comment `/* ... */` instead of `/* ... /*`

Answer (score -1):

You simply have your comment close the wrong way around your code works other than that

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vesanje</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            trenutna rec: <span id="trenutna_rec"></span>
            <br>
            broj pokusaja: <span id="br_pokusaja"></span>
            <br>
            trenutno slovo: <input type="text" id="slovo">
            <br>
            koriscena slova: <input type="text" id="koriscena_slova" readonly>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="zameni pojavljivanja" id="dugme">
        </div>

        <canvas id="platno" height="" width="">

        </canvas>

        <script type='text/javascript'> 
            window.alert("kliks");
            /*
            window.rec="javascript";
            window.alert("test");
            var trenutna_rec = document.querySelector("#trenutna_rec");
            var trenutna_rec_niska = new Array();
            for(let i=0; i<window.rec.length; i++){
                trenutna_rec_niska[i]= "_ ";
            }
            trenutna_rec.textContent = trenutna_rec_niska.join("");

            var br_pokusaja = document.querySelector("#br_pokusaja");
            var br_pokusaja_vrednost=0;
            br_pokusaja.textContent=0;

            var tekuce_slovo = document.querySelector("#slovo");

            var koriscena_slova = document.querySelector("#koriscena_slova");
            var koriscena_slova_niz = new Array();

            var dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
            dugme.onclick=function(){
                //procita tekuce slovo
                var ts=tekuce_slovo.value;

                var zamene=0;

                //spreciti unos unetih slova
                if(koriscena_slova_niz.indexOf(ts)!=-1){
                    return;
                    tekuce_slovo.value="";
                }

                //provelrimo da li se slovo nalazi u reci
                for(let i=0; i<window.rec.length; i++){
                    if(window.rez[i]==ts){
                        trenutna_rec_niska[i]=ts;
                        zamene++;
                    }
                }

                //izvrsimo zamenu ako je potrebno
                //ispisati novu tekucu rec
                trenutna_rec.textContent = trenutna_rec_niska.join("");

                //ispisati novi br pokusaja
                br_pokusaja_vrednost++;
                br_pokusaja.textContent = br_pokusaja_vrednost;

                //dopisemo korisceno slovo
                koriscena_slova_niz.push(ts);
                koriscena_slova.textContent=koriscena_slova_niz.join("");

                tekuce_slovo.value = "";
            }*/
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

you didn't terminate your comment right its `*/` you have `/*`. Change those two and the alert goes off

Comment: `window.alert` and `alert` is the same thing

Comment: as this is correct anwser, i dont know why it has been down voted.

Comment: ok I just never saw it been used, care to elaborate when this would be useful to use window.alert?

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Well if you have a local variable called `alert` then you would need `window.alert`... `window.alert` is "more correct" because just `alert` itself will look for variables with that name until it finds the top-most scope `window.alert`.

Comment: does that mean that there is a performance difference (however small)?